# Python - How to get the names of the drivers C: D: F: I:

Tags: python-3.x

I am developing a GUI in Python 3.6 using TKinter. I came to an impasse where I have to get the installed drivers' letters and their names the same way they appear in Windows Explorer. See attached figure.

With the code below I can get the letters of the drivers, but not the names.

```
drives = win32api.GetLogicalDriveStrings()
drives = drives.split('\000')[:-1]
```

Does anyone have a solution?

[Drivers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WFsJ1.png)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see what this question has to do with tkinter ...

You can use the GetVolumeInformation function:

```
names = []
for drive in drives:
  try:
    names.append(win32api.GetVolumeInformation(drive)[0])
  except:
    names.append('Volume not mounted') # No disk in drive
```

Comment: ('Win7', 1087985650, 255, 65470719, 'NTFS')

Comment: Looks like you left the `[0]` off.